# Request and use an Auth access token

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to send a request to a secured API. In order to do so I must acquire and use an auth token. I'm using spring to request token access to a REST Service.

I have the username and password, content-Type, url(api.xxxxxx.com/v1/access/token). After getting the token that will expire after 15 min, I need to get information from the API. The service returns JSON.

I'm not finding any clear information or code on how to start with that.

I was able to do a simple code to an api that does not need token

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-
quoters.cfapps.io/api/random",Quote.class);
    log.info(quote.toString());
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: we're missing a lot of information from you. what kind of token are you receiving? JWT? this is obviously an OAuth situation. trying googling spring and oauth client & see what comes up. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the token , I'm not sure how to do so, and how to send it in the header with Authorization and Bearer...etc.

Comment: Yes it is OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

Example for bearer token authentication:

First send a request with your credentials in order to receive access token:

```
    String username = "" // your username
    String password = "" // your password
    String userAndPass = username + ":" + password;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + 
    Base64Utility.encode(userAndPass.getBytes()));
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    String authUri = "" // uri to service which you get the token from
    ResponseEntity<AuthenticationToken> response =
    restTemplate.exchange(authUri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, 
    AuthenticationToken.class);
    String token = response.getBody().getToken();
```

AuthenticationToken class: (note that I'm using lombok to generate getters and setters, you can do it manually)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AuthenticationToken {

    @JsonProperty(value = "access_token")
    String token;

}
```

Now that you have an access to the token, you can add the authorization header to every other request like this:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<Quote> response = restTemplate.getForObject(
            "http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", 
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, Quote.class);
```

Comment: Your explanation helped on having a idea how to get the token first. I'm getting an error when running the first part here is the error I'm getting " POST request for "https://api.expeditors.com/v1/access/token" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler", what I have as credentials is content type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded and grant_type=client_credentials should I be replacing MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON? Where should I put the grant_type?

Comment: In this case, i think you need to pass your credentials as url parameters: api.xxxxxx.com/v1/access/token?username=yourusername&password=yourpassword. Then you don't need to add header at all. I don't know about the grant_type though, maybe put in url as well.